# Yii 2: new form to pass variables to another view with post

Tags: php, forms, yii2

with yii 2 i want to pass 3 variables from a view to another view. In my controller i've created an action that get this 3 variables and then open a view, but in the "start" view i can't write a working form :/

This is my starting view:

```
<?= Html::beginForm(['preview', 'type'=>0, 'start'=>'start', 'end'=>'end'], 'post', ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>

                <?=
                    \yii\widgets\MaskedInput::widget([
                        'name' => 'start',
                        'clientOptions' => ['placeholder' =>  'GG-MM-AAAA'],
                        'mask' => '99-99-9999',
                    ])
                ?>

                <?=
                \yii\widgets\MaskedInput::widget([
                    'name' => 'end',
                    'clientOptions' => ['placeholder' =>  'GG-MM-AAAA'],
                    'mask' => '99-99-9999',
                ])
                ?>

                <?= Html::submitButton('Go', ['class' => 'submit']) ?>

<?= Html::endForm() ?>
```

and this is my action:

```
public function actionPreview($type, $start, $end)
{
    return $this->redirect(['preview', 'type' => $type, 'start'=>$start, 'end'=>$end]);
}
```

But, when i push the button "Go", Yii 2 returns

> Bad Request (#400) - Missing required parameters: start,end

I've tried also this action:

```
public function actionPreview() //$type, $start, $end
{
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $type = $post['type'];
    $start = $post['start'];
    $end = $post['end'];
    return $this->redirect(['preview', 'type' => $type, 'start'=>$start, 'end'=>$end]);
}
```

But it returns this error:

> Undefined index: type /start / end

Any ideas?

**-------UPDATE--------**

Now rendering works, but i can't read the params from the starting view.

MyController:

```
public function actionPreview() //$type, $start, $end
{
    $type = Yii::$app->request->get('type');
    $start = Yii::$app->request->get('start');
    $end = Yii::$app->request->get('end');
    return $this->render('preview', [
        'type' => $type, 'start'=>$start, 'end'=>$end
    ]);
}
```

The Form in my View is the same that you can see above, but it sends generic params to next page (in short, it doesn't read the input field):

> start=start
>
> end=end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried in this wy

```
    <?php 

    $start = '1234560123';

    ?>
    <?=   Html::beginForm(['preview', ], 'post', ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>



                     <?=   \yii\widgets\MaskedInput::widget([
                            'name' => 'start',
                            'value' => $start,
                            'clientOptions' => ['placeholder' =>  'GG-MM-AAAA'],
                            'mask' => '99-99-9999',
                        ])
                    ?>
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Go', ['class' => 'submit']) ?>

    <?= Html::endForm() ?>
```

and work

If you have the error undefined variable then there are problem in controller for passing the vars.

For a correct view remeber the data in vars must match the mask...

And for the preview you should use post and not get

```
public function actionPreview() //$type, $start, $end
{
    $type = Yii::$app->request->post('type');
    $start = Yii::$app->request->post('start');
    $end = Yii::$app->request->post('end');
    return $this->render('preview', [
       'type' => $type, 'start'=>$start, 'end'=>$end
   ]);
}
```

Comment: It returns "Trying to get property of non-object".
The errors come from "$type = $post->type", $start = $post->start and  $end = $post->end.

Comment: Ok, now the rendering works. But i can't read the input field of the view.

Comment: Please explain better, you have an error for get property of non-object or no? And seem you are redirect to teh same action .... $this.>redirect(['preview',....

Comment: i've changed the code, if you see above i've updated code and problem. now the rendering works, the problem is the reading of the parameters from the form.

Comment: but i have new error(s)--> Undefined variable: start.

Comment: I have update the answer (the assign of vars was in wrog place)

Comment: I've already tried this solution, but it returns the same error (undefined variable). And if I try to initialize the variables at the top of the page, they don't change

Comment: The value of the fields are passed by value attribute and not name. Also the begin form don't need the field name.. I have update the anwer

Comment: also in this case, it returns "undefined variable" :/

Comment: the name of undefined?

Comment: the same: start/end. And, like i said previously, if I try to initialize the variables at the top of the page, the widgets don't change the value of the variables.

Comment: I have tried a test for the code with the vars assigner in view and work. I have update the answer for show the code..for test

Comment: Bah, i don't know why.. But nothing, it doesn't work. Nothing is changed from the precedent piece of code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. However, yes I've tried your code but the variables remain as I initialize they

Comment: But  I have initilized $start above the code for rendering. This mean the render code can't show  the value you passed should show '1234560123'.

Comment: I have update the answer. Only now i see you use Yii::$app->request->get('type'); instead of Yii::$app->request->post('type'); Try gettiting the value by post

Comment: Perfect! Now it woks!!
Thank you!!